# Why doesn't Buckethead play live shows any more?

Tags: live-music, buckethead

According to Buckethead's [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckethead#2010.E2.80.9313:_Departure_from_all_bands_and_projects.2C_and_early_Pikes) page, he played his last live on December 2012 and hasn't played anywhere since. His own [tour page](http://www.bucketheadland.com/tour/index.htm) doesn't have any info on any upcoming events.

Do we know why he has stopped playing live shows?

Comment: http://www.bucketheadland.com/tour/index.html is the correct URL for his (empty) tour page.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently after this question was posted [Buckethead announced tour dates](http://consequenceofsound.net/2016/04/buckethead-announces-first-tour-dates-in-four-years/) for April to June 2016. In the linked article, it says about Buckethead that:

> Since he stopped touring, he’s released a staggering 224 albums as part of his long-running *Pikes* series, including an unfathomable 118 last year alone.

Though it's not an official explanation, I could imagine that he was focusing on recording and releasing an insane number of albums rather than touring.